# what happens when add to cart button clicks in opencart

Tags: opencart

Can somebody please tell me, which function will execute when we click on 'Add to Cart' button in store front? which code or method will execute when Add to Cart button clicked? I observed that there some calculations takes place.

In view/theme/***/template/product/product.tpl

```
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
          &nbsp;
          <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" />
```

in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }
            } 
            alert(json['success']);
            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/palioxis/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
```

Can somebody brief what happens here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery code looks for a button with the id, `'button-cart'`.

Once it is clicked, it runs the Ajax code below. The data will be transmitted to `route=checkout/cart/add` url.

The file calls your `/controller/checkout/cart.php` file and looks for the `add()` function. The data pass to the `add()` function will be from 'data'.

Then if the data are passed correctly, the jQuery code would prompt an alert message from `json['success']` and load a DIV layer.

Otherwise, if the data were not passed correctly, it would give an error message on the page.

Let me know if this helps you understand it. I use Opencart.

Comment: jsmoove88. Thanks a ton. 
If i have mandatory options for a product (radio button/ checkbox), for calculations it takes the data for the only those fields which is selected. I did not get where this calculation happens? I mean how it knows that these fields are selected/checked?

Comment: This calculation happens in the Add() function in /catalog/controller/checkout/cart. When a visitor clicks on the add button, the scripts would look to see if there are existing data in JSON for this user, and then if there is, it would get the product information then add it together. Once it is added, it would write back to JSON data. Hope this helps.

Comment: And note that the actual saving of the cart (`$this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);`  - the one I'm looking for) happens in cart in the library `library/cart/cart.php` again `add` function with a bunch of parameters.